# Growing a circular array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I am trying to write a generic Queue in the form of an array.  Everything seems to work if I set the arraySize to a specific value but if I attempt to grow the array every time it becomes full it is causing the values to be overwritten.  I appreciate any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.  Thanks

HEADER:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_ARRAY
#define QUEUE_ARRAY

template <typename E>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue();            //constructor
    //Queue(const Queue &obj);  //copy constructor note:the copy constructor is optional
    ~Queue();           //destructor
    void enqueue(const E& e);
    const E& dequeue(); //throw(QueueEmpty);  //note that the use of exceptions is optional
    const E& front() const; //throw(QueueEmpty); //note that the use of exceptions is optional
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;

private:
    int frontElem, rear, numEntries, arraySize;
    E* queueArray;
};
#endif //
```

QA CPP:

```
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename E>
Queue<E>::Queue() {
    numEntries = 0;
    arraySize = 1;
    frontElem = 0;
    rear = 0;
    queueArray = new E[arraySize];
}

template<typename E>
Queue<E>::~Queue() {
    delete[] queueArray;
}

template<typename E>
void Queue<E>::enqueue(const E & e) {

    if (numEntries == arraySize) {
        arraySize = arraySize * 2;
        E* temp = new E[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
            temp[i] = queueArray[(frontElem + i) % arraySize];
        }
        delete queueArray;
        queueArray = temp;
    }
    queueArray[rear] = e;
    rear = (rear + 1) % arraySize;
    numEntries++;
}

template<typename E>
const E& Queue<E>::dequeue() {

    E &temp = queueArray[frontElem];
    frontElem = ((frontElem + 1) % arraySize);
    numEntries--;

    return temp;
}

template<typename E>
const E& Queue<E>::front() const {
    return queueArray[frontElem];
}

template<typename E>
int Queue<E>::size() const {

    return numEntries;
}

template<typename E>
bool Queue<E>::empty() const {

    return (numEntries == 0);
}
```

QA EXPAND:

```
#include "QueueArray.cpp"

using namespace std;

template class Queue<int>;
```

QA TEST:

```
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Queue<int> *s;
    s = new Queue<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++){
        s->enqueue(i);
    }

    while (!s->empty()) {
        cout << "Dequeue: " << s->dequeue() << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    delete s;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and examine the contents of your queue during the reallocation, what observations did you make?

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to place the template implementation in a cpp file and then include the cpp file. Much ugliness results. I strongly recommend keeping the template implementation in the header. If you must split the class and the implementation, put them both in headers and have the definition header include the implementation header.

Comment: Sam, it seems like it is resetting my rear int value for whatever the value i set arraySize too.  But I am not really sure why this is happening.

Comment: `rear = (rear + 1) % arraySize;` when `rear == arraySize` what is the output value of `rear`? Then consider what happens if this happens with when you fill up the array and will resize on the next enqueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy the existing queue data into the newly allocated buffer in `enqueue`, you copy the element at element `frontElem` to element 0.  What you don't have, and need, is `frontElem = 0;` after copying the data.  `rear` will also need to be updated.

And `delete queueArray` should be `delete [] queueArray`.  Since you're allocating arrays, you need to delete arrays.